# PCRE-regex Use grep to exclude a capturing group

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression, pcre

I am using `GNU grep` with the `-P` PCRE Regex support for matching strings from a file. The input file has lines containing strings like:

```
FOO_1BAR.zoo.2.someString:More-RandomString (string here too): 0.45654343
```

I want to capture the numbers `2` and `0.45654343` from the above line. I used a regEx

```
grep -Po ".zoo.\K[\d+](.*):\ (.*)$" file
```

But this is producing me a result as

```
2.someString:More-RandomString (string here too): 0.45654343
```

I am able to get the first number from the first capturing group as `2`, and also to match a capturing group at the end of the line. But I am not able to skip the words/lines between two capturing groups.

I know for a fact that I have a group `(.*)` that is capturing those words in the middle. What I've tried to do is include another `\K` to ignore it as

```
grep -Po ".zoo.\K[\d+](.*):\K (.*)$" file
```

But that gave me only the second capture group as `0.556984`.

Also with a non-capturing group with the `(?:)` syntax as

```
grep -Po ".zoo.\K[\d+](?=.someString:More-RandomString (string here too)):\ (.*)$"
```

But this gave me nothing. What am I missing here?

Comment: You're missing basic understanding of how Perl regexps are supposed to work.  You're also missing basic sense of not trying to do this with a single `grep` command.

Comment: @SatoKatsura: I wanted to use a single `grep` and I hoped it would be possible. And the reason for `You're missing basic understanding of how Perl regexps are supposed to work`? I did a decent attempt to solving the issue

Comment: `\K` doesn't do what you seem to think it does.  Neither does `[\d+]`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura: Why do you think that? Can you point me how is it incorrect?

Comment: Because (1) it doesn't make sense to have more than one `\K` in the same regexp, and (2) how do you explain the output of something like this: `echo 1+2 | grep -Po '[\d+]'`?

Comment: @SatoKatsura: Appreciate your comments. Will learn more about PCRE syntaxes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`grep`'s name comes after the `g/re/p` `ed` command. Its primary purpose is to print the lines that match a regexp. It's not its role to edit the content of those lines. You have `sed` (the stream editor) or `awk` for that.

Now, some `grep` implementations, starting with GNU `grep` added a `-o` option to print the matched portion of each line (what is matched by the regexp, not its capture groups). You've got some `grep` implementation like GNU's again (with `-P`) or `pcregrep` that support PCREs for their regexps.

`pcregrep` actually added a `-o<n>` option to print the content of a capture group. So you could do:

```
pcregrep -o1 -o2 --om-separator=' ' '.zoo.(\d+).*:\s+(.*)'
```

But here, the obvious standard solution is to use `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/^.*\.zoo\.\([0-9]\{1,\}\).*:[[:space:]]\{1,\}/\1 /p'
```

Or if you want perl regexps, use perl:

```
perl -lne 'print "$1 $2" if /\.zoo\.(\d+).*:\s+(.*)/'
```

With GNU `grep`, if you don't mind the matches to appear on different lines, you can do:

```
$ grep -Po '\.zoo\.\K\d+|:\s+\K.*' < file
2
0.45654343
```

Note that while `\K` resets the start of the matched portion, that doesn't mean you can get away with the two parts of the alternation overlapping.

```
grep -Po '.zoo.(\K\d+|.: \K.)'
```

would not work, just like `echo foobar | grep -Po 'foo|foob'` wouldn't work (at printing both `foo` and `foob`). `foo|foob` first matches `foo` and then `grep` looks for potential other matches in the input after the `foo`, so starting at the `b` of `bar`, so can't find any more after that.

Above with `grep -Po '\.zoo\.\K\d+|:\s+\K.*'`, we only look for `:<spaces><anything>` in the second part of the alternation. That does match in the part that is after `.zoo.<digits>` but that also means it would find those `:<spaces><anything>` anywhere in the input, not only when they follow `.zoo.<digits>`.

There is a way to work around that though, using another PCRE special operator: `\G`. `\G` matches at the start of the subject. For a single match, that's equivalent to `^`, but with multiple matches (think of `sed`/`perl`'s `g` flag in `s/.../.../g`) like with `-o` where `grep` tries to find all the matches in the line, that also matches after the end of the previous match. So if you make it:

```
grep -Po '\.zoo\.\K\d+|(?!^)\G.*:\s+\K.*'
```

Where `(?!^)` is a negative look-ahead operator that means *not at the beginning of the line*, that `\G` will only match after a previous successful (non-empty) match, so `.*:\s+\K.*` will only match if it follows a previous successful match, and that can only be the `.foo.<digits>` one since the other part of the alternation matches til the end of the line.

On an input like:

```
.zoo.1.zoo.2 tar: blah
```

That would output:

```
1
2
blah
```

Though. If you did not want that, you'd also want the first part of the alternation to only match at the beginning of the line. Something like

```
grep -Po '^.*?\.zoo\.\K\d+|(?!^)\G.*:\s+\K.*'
```

That still outputs `2` on an input like `.zoo.2 no colon character` or `.zoo.2 blah:`. Which you could work around with a look-ahead operator in the first part of the alternation, and look for at least one non-space after `:<spaces>` (and also using `$`  to avoid issues with non-characters)

```
grep -Po '^.*?\.zoo\.\K\d+(?=.*:\s+\S.*$)|(?!^)\G.*:\s+\K\S.*$'
```

You'd probably need a few pages of comments to explain that regexp, so I would still go for the straightfoward `sed`/`perl` solutions...

Comment: Appreciate your answer, did I miss something in my question. Do you mean that I simply can't do what I intended to do with a single `grep`?

Comment: @Inian, You can't easily with a single invocation of the current version of GNU `grep` (the one I suppose you're trying to use as it seems it supports `-P` and `-o` though that could also be the one of FreeBSD/OS/X that are rewrites of GNU grep). You can with other `grep` implementations like `pcregrep`. But I argue you're picking the wrong tool for the task. Use `sed` to edit streams.

Comment: I am quite easily able to do this only using bash native regex as `[[ "$string" =~ .zoo.([[:digit:]]+).*:\ (.*)$ ]]` and print as `printf "%s\t%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"  "${BASH_REMATCH[2]//[[:blank:]]}"`

Comment: Thought `grep` could do this in someway. Anyway am accepting this answer agreeing it can't be done with a single invocation and some useful stuff on `pcregrep` which I haven't used before.

Comment: Actually, the syntax `grep -Po '\.zoo\.\K\d+|: \K.*'` worked fine for me? But is there a way you can tell me to remove the whitespaces in the 2nd capturing group? It is currently printing it with a space in a new line.

Comment: See edit. Replaced one space with `\s+` as I suppose you had more than one space after the `:`. Also added a way to make sure the `:\s+.*` only matches if `.zoo.<digits>` has been found beforehand.

Comment: Now this a great answer!